# How to add a horizontal loader in Webview

Tags: react-native, webview

How to add a horizontal loader like this in a react native webview.
[Like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVWXW.jpg)
I can only find activity indicator as a spinner.Could any one help me thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Add a layout on the same position just above the web view with setting it's opacity and add your custom loader on that layout. or you can use custom gif on the layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can try progress indicator above web-view and change its colour and size according to your need.

**Please check following npm package**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-progress

[image]

**You can put following code above webview**

```
import * as Progress from 'react-native-progress';

<Progress.Bar progress={0.3} width={200} />
<Progress.Pie progress={0.4} size={50} />
<Progress.Circle size={30} indeterminate={true} />
<Progress.CircleSnail color={['red', 'green', 'blue']} />
```